# independence of ols coefficient and estimated standard deviation

Tags: regression, correlation

Is there an error in the reasoning in these lecture notes from a linear models course at EPFL? The author aims to establish that under the standard fixed design linear regression model with gaussian errors, the coefficient estimate $\hat{\beta}$ is independent of the residual variance estimate $S^2$. He writes,

"If $e=y-X\hat{\beta}$ is independent of $\hat{y}=X\hat{\beta}$, then $S^2=e^Te/(n-p)$ will obviously be independent of
$\hat{\beta}$. Now notice that: ..."

And he goes on to show that $e$ is independent of $\hat{y}$ in the usual way, one is a projection onto the column space of $X$, the other is the projection onto its orthogonal complement, and the distributions are jointly gaussian so uncorrelatedness implies independence.

But I don't follow what he suggests is "obvious", i.e., why $e$ being independent of $X\hat{\beta}$ implies $e$ is independent of $\hat{\beta}$, since $X$ need not be invertible. In fact, while it is easy to visualize the independence of $e$ and $\hat{y}$ in terms of projections, I don't know how to visualize the relationship between $e$ and $\hat{\beta}$, the projection scaled by the squared norm of $X$, in a way that suggests uncorrelatedness.

Comment: $\hat \beta$ is a function of $\hat Y = X \hat \beta$, since $\hat \beta = (X'X)^{-1} X'\hat Y$.

Comment: @BigBendRegion oh right, betahat must be a function of yhat when the columns of X are independent.